# Only show one word if there are another words same in listview

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

i have another question and i want to know how to solve it.... I hope someone can help me with this. Some advices will be appreciated. Here is my problem, in my listview, i have a list of things :

```
- car
- sugar
- salt
- car
- sugar
- poll
```

Just like what u see, i have some same words in the list, this is my problem. How can i show only one of them at a time (the same words) in the list view ???? FYI: the listview from the database.

Any suggestion will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL use `GROUP BY` so the item won't duplicate

For more details see [MySQL GROUP BY example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

**Edited**

[SQLite - GROUP BY](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_group_by.htm)

Comment: No, its SQLite.... i already tagged it, in case some people need to know. Can i do the same in SQLite ???

Comment: SQL-MySQL-SQLite not much different